# Rewrite URL on windows 10 pc?

Tags: linux, windows, reverse-proxy, rewrite, url

I'm not a pro in networking, but a software engineer, so don't kill me if it's not possible, but here's my question with a little "intro".

So we have a server that is currently at public static ip 69.xx.xx.xx and we're switching our supplier and they don't allow us to keep our public ip, so they will switch us to 74.xx.xx.xx.

Now, we have a software (Java .jar file), which we don't have the code for, that has the IP 69.xx.xx.xx hard coded in and that we will be replacing in the next 6 months. But for now, is there a way (Trashy or not, we just want to switch our connexion as fast as possible) to write a rule in the windows 10 computer that runs the software that rewrites the URL 69.xx.xx.xx to 74.xx.xx.xx for every HTTP or HTTPS request that it makes?

I know it's not really safe nor recommended, but it would be really helpful since we want to get out of this provided as soon as possible and we won't have the ip 69.xx.xx.xx anymore and that's the only problem holding us back. If you have any solution or something, thank you so much in advance, please don't kill me with minus points, I'm new on this forum and completely aware that it's an unusual demand!

Comment: It can be done fairly easily on the client computer if it runs Linux, but I do not believe it is possible on Windows.

Comment: Okay thank you so much! Do you have any other info on how I could do it on linux? ^^'